# cut and paste filename with spaces into a command

Tags: linux, command-line, terminal, copy-paste

when i type `ls` or `locate` as an output i get "`a file.txt`" (there is a space between "a" and "file.txt".

i highlight it with a mouse and than paste it with a middle button.

now i have to put \ after "a" so that "`a file.txt`" can be read in a command such as "`ls a\ file.txt`" now if the file name is a name of some book that has a lot of spaces it takes time to modify the name. is there a way to do this quick?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can prepend a quote before you paste then close it afterwards. 
So you'd start your command

```
ls "
```

Then paste your text

```
ls "a file.txt
```

Then close the quote and hit enter

```
ls "a file.txt"
```

instead of

```
ls a\ file.txt
```

You don't have to escape every space if you quote the string.

Note: You can use single quotes too and that will prevent variable expansion if you get something like a file named $test

```
ls '$test'
```

would not be the same as

```
ls "$test"
```

With an empty variable, the second example will list the current directory, not just the file $test

Comment: Nice, I didn't know this works :)

Answer (score 0):

The backslash is used as an escape character for the shell to treat that space that comes after literally. Try replacing the spaces with underscores or dashes.

Comment: i'm using existing file names that i get from internet. they already have a space character

Comment: Don't give in to the oppression of the shell! Use human-readable names and quote them appropriately. Computers exist to serve humans, not the other way around. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Some terminal emulators (e.g., Mac OS X Terminal) have a command for pasting text with quoting. In Terminal it's **Edit > Paste Escaped Text**; it inserts backslashes before special characters. Your terminal program may have a similar command.